# Encode xPath as link

Tags: asp.net, xpath

I am encoding the link contained in a RSS in this way:

```
<div class="link">
  <span> <%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(XPath("link").ToString())%> </span>
</div>
```

the above is returning the link of such rss in text format, for example like this:

> http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/EuropeanRailwayReview/~3/0pxP3t3rge8/

but as text not as clickable link.

Is there a way to get it returned as a hyperlink that can be clicked to navigate to the relevant address? Or, even better as something to click without showing the url?

Comment: Try show the raw output of what you are getting, and what you expect, rather than just describing it.  It's hard to tell exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @MikeMooney sorry for that, I thought was clear. I have added an example of the output I am getting out. But as I said, the output is plain text and I would like to get a link that can be clicked to go to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="link">
  <span> <a href="<%#XPath("link").ToString())%>"><%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(XPath("link").ToString())%></a> </span>
</div>
```

Or this:

```
<div class="link">
 <span> <a href="<%#XPath("link").ToString())%>">Link to Article</a> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats working perfectly. Thank you a lot. Do you think there is a way to display it as "Link to article" instead of showing the full url that is quite ugly?

Comment: Sure, I just added that to the answer